# Open only one popup in list.map(user)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

```
export default function CreateForm() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);



    return (
            <div className="display">
                {UsersList.map((user) => {
                    return (
                            <div>
                                <h1>{user.id}</h1>
                                <h1> {user.Name}</h1>
                                <h1> {user.userName}</h1>
                                   <button onClick={() => {
                                    dispatch(deleteUser({ id: beauty.id }));}}>
                                    Delete User
                                </button>
                                    <button onClick={()=>{
                                        setIsOpen(true);
                                    }}>View in popup</button>
                                    <Modal open={isOpen} onClose={()=>setIsOpen(false)}>
                                        <h2> {User.Information}</h2>
                                    </Modal>

                            </div>
                    );})}
            </div>
    );
}
```

I am new to react and redux. I try to display a list of users on the webpage and add a popup box to each user. But when I click the button "View in popup" below a user, all users' popup boxes open, but I only want to open the popup box for that user. I realize this is because I use my function setIsOpen in the map, and setIsOpen does not associate with a specific userID. But I don't know how to fix this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of objects, but in state you're only tracking a single boolean value for whether or not "the modal" is open:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
```

So either *all of them* are open or *all of them* are closed.  Instead, track an identifier indicating *which* modal is open.  For example:

```
const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState();
```

To update it, set the relevant `id` value to that state:

```
<button onClick={()=>{
  setOpenModal(user.id);
}}>View in popup</button>
```

And to use it, check if the current record matches that value:

```
open={openModal === user.id}
```

Then to close it, simply clear the value:

```
onClose={() => setIsOpen(undefined)}
```